# kernel panic error in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, virtualization, xen

Before installing xen hypervisor my ubuntu 12.10 was working fine, but after installing xen I am unable to boot my ubuntu. The error is:

`/bin/sh:error while loading shared liberaries:libc.so.6 cannot open shared obj etc file:no such file or directory
[1.279236] kernel panic -not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode =0*00007f00`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a known problem, and you will find the description (and suggestions how to deal with it) here: http://wiki.prgmr.com/mediawiki/index.php/Chapter_15:_Troubleshooting#The_Importance_of_Disk_Drivers_.28initrd_Problems.29

> "The underlying problem here—at least in this case—is that the domU
>   kernel doesn’t have the necessary drivers compiled in, and the ramdisk
>   was not specified. (...) Nearly all distro kernels come with a minimal
>   kernel and require an initrd with the disk driver to finish booting.
>   These messages may simply come from the kernel before the initrd has
>   loaded, or they can indicate a serious problem if the initrd doesn’t
>   contain the necessary drivers."

This is a highly specific problem, and I suggest that you turn to stackoverflow to solve it.