# Kernel panic - not syncing : attempted to kill int ! exit code=0x00007f00

Tags: kernel

While I was upgrading to Ubuntu 15 (the development version), my system crashed. After I restarted the laptop, I saw a kernel panic. I also did a memtestx86 which didn't find any error.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

```
more info :
```

Before doing upgrade i have changed my default desktop to gnome which by entering wrong commands i lost some packages .to revert the previous desktop i removed all the packages and then installed them then i face that some packages weren't still installed . after i run terminal and started to upgrade ( i found it good to troubleshot the problem by upgrading somehow ) however after crash i got that screen by the way i have faced another screen after this one which backed to the first again

Comment: See if you can boot into a LiveUSB. Mostly related to memory issues or BIOS stuff.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have been able to create a bootable USB but that is NO USE. It takes me to a completely different looking ubuntu with no files present and my regular user not present. I want to restore what I had.

Answer (score 4):

This is not "memory issues or BIOS stuff" at all.  The panic screen — which you have not transcribed in full in your question but really should so that the text will be indexed and people will find it in the future — says `Comm: sh`.  That, plus the knowledge that this is the panic screen that results when process #1 exits with status code 127, tells us that you booted with `init=/bin/sh`, or that this is an `init` shell script that is provided in an initramfs.

In the former case, you explicitly did something to cause the shell to exit.  In the latter case, something aborted within the shell script, which would have most likely printed an error message that has unfortunately scrolled off the screen.

You need to find out what that error is.  Without it, you cannot diagnose this problem, as it could be any one of a number of *very different* things.  Here are *just some* of the various possibilities:

- [kernel panic error in ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321125/) —

  ```
  /bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries:libc.so.6 cannot open shared object file:no such file or directory
  ```
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159565 —

  ```
  /bin/sh: nodevfs: No such file or directory
  ```
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1421117 —

  ```
  /init: line 325: chroot: not found
  /bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash
  ```
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244750/ —

  ```
  Targeted filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
  ```

Booting with a serial console (that can scroll back or display more than the 24 lines that your laptop's console does) attached is one way to find this out.  Persuading the boot loader to switch the screen into, say, 50 line mode would be another.

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195978/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197472/5132

Comment: Before doing upgrade i have changed my default desktop to gnome which by entering wrong commands i lost some packages .to revert the previous desktop i removed all the packages and then installed them then i face that some packages weren't still installed . after i run terminal and started to upgrade ( i found it good to troubleshot the problem by upgrading somehow ) however after crash i got that screen by the way i have faced another screen after this one which backed to the first again .

Comment: Really educating answer. Thanks for this. Will save me time swapping RAM the next time. :P

Comment: I just want a quick solution to fix it. Steps to take to restore everything including all my files and programs.